# PHP output buffering with template file results in line breaks and empty paragraphs

Tags: php, output, buffer, line-breaks, ob-start

I'm using ob_start() etc. to buffer some output while including a php template file with HTML code. Heres the template file example:

```
<div class="prefix-box__thumb">
    <a class="prefix-box__image-link"
       href="<?php echo $this->get_product_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->get_product_link_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        <img class="prefix-box__image" src="<?php echo $this->get_product_image(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->get_product_image_alt(); ?>" />
    </a>

    <?php if ( $this->get_product_rating() ) { ?>
        <div class="prefix-box__rating">
            <?php echo $this->get_product_star_rating(); ?>

            <?php if ( $this->get_product_reviews() ) { ?>
                <div class="prefix-box__reviews"><?php echo $this->get_product_reviews(); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

As you can see I indented the lines to make it more readable for me as a developer.

Unfortunately on some websites (not on my servers, so I cant reproduce it) these indentions result in line breaks and empty paragraphs when returning or rather printing the ob_get_clean result.

As an example for the broken result:

```
<a class="prefix-box__image-link" <br="" ... >...</a>

or 

<p> </p>
```

For the line breaks I thought about using `$str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $str);` but I'm not sure if this will fit because - as I wrote above - I cannot reproduce the wrong output on my own.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what problem you're trying to solve here. You state that this code does not produce undesired results for you, but you also state you have undesired results (*supposedly not ones you can reproduce yourself*). Where do these undesired results come from? Where is the code that does produce them?

Comment: The problem occurs on a website of one of my plugin users, for me everything works fine. And as I showed in the example snippet in this case the link is broken because the from my template at the top the line break was converted to a break which was inserted inside the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the line I mentioned above and luckily this solves the problem and removed the line breaks from the buffering output:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $str);
```